# 2D array processing with immutable states

Tags: algorithm, scala, immutability

have algorithm for finding "Hourglass" and calculation sum

```
object Hourglass2D {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in)
    var n = sc.nextInt()
    var arr = new Array[Int](n)
    for (arr_i <- 0 until n) {
      arr(arr_i) = sc.nextInt()
    }

    var res = -2147483648
    for (i <- 0 until arr.length - 2) {
      for (j <- 0 until arr.length - 2) {
        val sum = checkSum(arr, i, j, j + 2) + checkSum(arr,  i + 1, j + 1, j + 1) + checkSum(arr, i + 2, j, j + 2)
        if (sum > res) res = sum
      }
    }

    println(res)
  }

  private def checkSum(arr: Array[Array[Int]], row: Int, first: Int, last: Int) = {
    var sum = -1
    for (i <- first until last + 1) {
      sum = sum + arr(row)(i)
    }
    sum + 1
  }
```

As you can see I used mutable states, like var. Any ideas how to use val instead of var ?

Thanks.

Comment: uhm, this code doesn't compile - `arr` has type `Array[Int]`, and it is passed as first argument to `checkSum(arr: Array[Array[Int]], ...)`. ?

Comment: Why it doesn't compile ? See : `scala> val a = Array.fill(10)(Array.ofDim[Int](10)) a: Array[Array[Int]] ..... scala> a(0)(1) res1: Int = 0`

Comment: @alifirat yes, of course one can create a `Array[Array[Int]]`, that's not my point - in the code above the OP creates a `var arr = new Array[Int](n)` and passes it to a function expecting an `Array[Array[Int]]`... so I can't figure out what the code is trying to do.

Comment: @TzachZohar sorry, I read too quickly, you're right !

Answer (score 2):

There's some issue with the construction of `arr`, so I'll skip it. You can build the sums using a `for {...} yield` expression, and then add the constant and find the maximum using `max`:

```
object Hourglass2D {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val arr: Array[Array[Int]] = ???

    val sums: Seq[Int] = for {
      i <- 0 until arr.length - 2
      j <- 0 until arr.length - 2
    } yield checkSum(arr, i,     j,     j + 2) + 
            checkSum(arr, i + 1, j + 1, j + 1) +
            checkSum(arr, i + 2, j,     j + 2)

    val res = (sums :+ -2147483648).max

    println(res)
  }

  // as suggested in comment:
  private def checkSum(arr: Array[Array[Int]], row: Int, first: Int, last: Int) = {
    arr(row).slice(first, last+1).sum
  }
}
```

Comment: right - copied this without thinking, updated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write the first function using two `foldLeft` :

```
val res = -2147483648
      (0 until (arr.length-2)).foldLeft(res) { case (acc, i) =>
        (0 until (arr.length-2)).foldLeft(acc) { case (acc2, j) =>
          val sum = checkSum(arr, i, j, j + 2) + checkSum(arr,  i + 1, j + 1, j + 1) + checkSum(arr, i + 2, j, j + 2)
          if(sum > acc2) sum else acc2
        }
        }
```

You can write the seconds function using `foldLeft` :

```
(first until (last+1)).foldLeft(0) { case (acc, i) => acc + arr(row)(i)}
```

As @TzachZohar mentionned, there is some typing problems !

Comment: thanks, how about - var res = -2147483648 ? any ideas ?

Comment: You don't do anything with the result of the foldLefts? I think you probably meant `val res = 0 until (arr.length-2)).foldLeft(-2147483648) { case ....`?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPal I supposed the `foldLeft` as the last expression of a Scala function so no need to put the value into a `val` for me.

Comment: Not with a `println(res)` as your next statement :) Also, the two loops are basically doing a `max` of the checksum, and it might be simpler to code it like that.

Comment: Ahaha thanks @TheArchetypalPal to pointing this stupid error :)

Comment: Moving my comment: `checkSum` could be done with `arr(row).slice(first, last+1).sum`. And why `until (last+1)`, that's the same as `to last`?

Comment: You're right for the two remarks. I often use `foldLeft` so I proposed my solution. You seems to have a good solution too so you add a new post no ?

Comment: @tzachzohar's answer covers my points, I'd only be duplicating